# PHP Select Query for comparing 2 values (if they match) from different mysql tables

Tags: mysql

New to PHP got a quiz. Have a input form for answers that goes to a mysql table in db 15 Questions/15Answers. And also within the db a questions table an ID field that goes to 15 and a correct answer field.

Questions Table:

- Questions_ID - int 11 /PK / Not NULL
- question - text / Not NULL
- rightanswer - text / Not NULL

Answer Table:

- Answers_ID - int 11 / PK / Not NULL
- inputanswer1 - varchar 255 / Not NULL
- inputanswer2 - varchar 255 / Not NULL
- inputanswer3 - varchar 255 / Not NULL

I want to know using this method of checking from the questions table the correct answer which I've done below but issue I'm having is than matching that with another table where the input answers are stored.

Question is what's the operator used to get saying 'equal to' something else and seeing if they match. And it's this all in 1 select query.

Questions Table

```
SELECT fieldname (rightanswer) FROM tablename (Questions)  WHERE ID = 1;
SELECT fieldname FROM tablename WHERE Id = 2;
```

This above code is working and doing the first part I want it to do which is selecting the "rightanswer" from "Questions" table with the first question ID of "1" now need help with second part of matching/comparing that to where the answers are inputted which is in "Answers" table with starting with "inputanswer1"

Looking for does the "rightanswer" from "Questions" table match "inputanswer1" from "Answers" table.

??? Answers Table

```
SELECT fieldname FROM tablename;
```

Comment: A simple JOIN to the 2nd table should work. Since you didn't include the table schemas, it's hard to provide an example.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Is table schemas simply the data structure fields, data types, keys etc ...

Comment: Yes, basically the CREATE TABLE statement with the indexes

Comment: @SloanThrasher Like so edited my post?

Comment: Not a create table statement, but it should do for now. One thing, the right answer column is shown as text. If you are going to compare to the 3 answer column in answers, it should be the same type (varchar),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below assumes that you are relating the questions table rows to the answers table 
rows using the ID columns in each. But you show the ID column in answers to be a primary key.

Just edit the ON clause to the correct relationship.

As mentioned in my comment above, the column `rightanswer` in the questions table should have the same type as the columns you compare it to (IOW, varchar(255))

```
SELECT
    a.`ID`,
    a.`question`,
    a.`rightanswer`,
    b.`ID` as `aID`,
    b.`inputanswer1`,
    b.`inputanswer2`,
    b.`inputanswer3`,
FROM `questions` a 
JOIN `answers` b
ON a.`ID` = b.`ID`
WHERE a.`rightanswer` = b.`inputanswer1`
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Table schemas supplied by OP

```
CREATE TABLE `quiz`.`Questions` ( 
    `Questions_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `question` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `rightanswer` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Questions_ID`)
)
ENGINE = MyISAM; 

CREATE TABLE `quiz`.`Answers` ( 
    `Questions_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `inputanswer1` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `inputanswer2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `inputanswer3` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `inputanswer4` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `inputanswer5` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Questions_ID`)
) 
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the response and input will look into this, looks like as you mentioned above a SQL Join Query. Can a simple select query work as I mentioned where I started instead of a Join Query. If simply selecting one field = another field from 2 tables.  `SELECT fieldname (rightanswer) FROM tablename (Questions)  WHERE Questions_ID = 1;`

Comment: The join simplifies dealing with the results.

Comment: Thanks will try your query method above. So simply what're the first steps you mention "ID columns in each. But you show the ID column in answers to be a primary key." in your query which ID you using? And guessing I'll need to make sure that ID is in both tables named exactly same using same data types is this correct? First thing to do? Not sure what you mean by "Just edit the ON clause to the correct relationship." what do I do.

Comment: Since your description of the tables did not include a foreign key linking the two tables, I used the "id" columns as placeholders in my answer. How are the two tables related? IOW, how do you know which answers go with which questions?

Comment: Ah right understand. Just looking at my table structure believe there's isn't a definite relation between the 2. Questions table having the Questions_ID being PK with id numbers of 1-15 and Answers table simply recording the answers in inputanswer1 to 15. Just by collecting from the options of the quiz. It's just a matter the quiz and tables are built following the questions numbers followed exactly with the answers in the correct order and right format from 1-15. So I'm guessing I'll firstly need to setup a FK? Will that be Questions_ID and having them in both tables?

Comment: Sounds right to me, You should have multiple rows in the answers table with the same value (the question id), and different students (or whatever), If you edit your question and add the table schemas (the CREATE TABLE statements) I may be able to offer more help

Comment: Right thanks. Not familiar with how to get the table schemas which you mention is basically the create table statements. Is it literally the create table statements within mysql for creation of the table and fields and data types etc ... Which table you requesting this for?

Comment: Both of the tables, questions and answers.

Comment: Is this what you're requesting? 

`CREATE TABLE "quiz"."Questions" ( "Questions_ID" INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , "question" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , "rightanswer" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ("Questions_ID")) ENGINE = MyISAM;`  

`CREATE TABLE "quiz"."Answers" ( "Questions_ID" INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , "inputanswer1" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , "inputanswer2" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , "inputanswer3" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , "inputanswer4" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , "inputanswer5" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ("Questions_ID")) ENGINE = MyISAM;`

Comment: Question: The answers table, does it contain the multiple choice answers for the question, or answers entered by users? I suspect it is the former. If that is the case, you should be using only one table since there would be a one to one relationship between the two tables.

Comment: As you mentioned it only contains the answers from the users from a php form which contains the multiple choice answers but only storing the 1 answer a user chooses when they submit that form and data goes into that table. If that's the case as you mention at the end so it's best to simply have 1 table containing the Questions_ID, question, rightanswer and inputanswer1 will it be something like this.

Comment: The first sentence in your comment doesn't make a lot of sense (or my brain is misfiring ;-)  The user's answer shouldn't be stored with the source of the question. IMHO, you should have a table containing the Question text, a list of multiple choice answers presented to the user, and some indication of which answer is correct. Then have a 2nd table to store a user's answers. It would have: FK to the question, their answer (number), an FK to the user's record. You need have a table of users. You might also have a table of Question Groups if you might have more than one test/survey.